# How to insert Normal distribution in multiple subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, normal-distribution

So I have multiple plots, using subplot and I would like to add normal distribution on it. I haven't had much luck finding information on how to do this for each individual subplot.

This is what my subplots look like so far:
[image: graphs]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

This is the code I'm working with so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

def grade_distribution():
    
    # importing datasets
    df=pd.read_csv('assets/class_grades.csv')
    

    
    VALID_GRADES = ['A+','A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'D-', 'E']
    NUMERIC_GRADES = [4.3,4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0, 0.7, 0.0]
    grade_point_dict = dict(zip(VALID_GRADES, NUMERIC_GRADES))

    df['ECON101_grade'] = df.replace({'ECON101_grade' : grade_point_dict})['ECON101_grade']
    df['EECS545_grade'] = df.replace({'EECS545_grade' : grade_point_dict})['EECS545_grade']
    df['ENGLISH125_grade'] = df.replace({'ENGLISH125_grade' : grade_point_dict})['ENGLISH125_grade']
    df['MATH217_grade'] = df.replace({'MATH217_grade' : grade_point_dict})['MATH217_grade']
    df['DATASCI306_grade'] = df.replace({'DATASCI306_grade' : grade_point_dict})['DATASCI306_grade']
    df['STATS250_grade'] = df.replace({'STATS250_grade' : grade_point_dict})['STATS250_grade']
    

    
    cols_to_plot = ['ECON101_grade', 'EECS545_grade','ENGLISH125_grade','MATH217_grade', 'DATASCI306_grade', 'STATS250_grade']
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2)
    fig.set_size_inches(30, 20)

    
    for col, ax in zip(cols_to_plot, axs.flatten()):
        dftemp = df[col].value_counts()
        ax.bar(dftemp.index, list(dftemp))
        ax.set_title(col)
        ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=30)

    axs[0, 0].set_title("ECON 101 Grade")
    axs[0, 1].set_title("EECS 545 Grade")
    axs[1, 0].set_title("ENGLISH 125 Grade")
    axs[1, 1].set_title("MATH 217 Grade")
    axs[2, 0].set_title("DATASCI 306 Grade")
    axs[2, 1].set_title("STATS 250 Grade")
    
    plt.show()
    
grade_distribution()
```

Comment: I guess you just need to add ax.plot(x_normal, y_normal) inside the loop. Or are you asking how to get the mean and standard deviation from your samples?

Comment: Also note that `ax.bar(...)` uses a default bar width of `0.8` while `dftemp.index` has values at distances of `0.3` and `0.4` apart. This makes the bar overlap quite a lot.

Comment: Using `dfl` from my previous answer `sns.displot(data=dfl, col='classes', col_wrap=3, x='grades_num', kind='hist', kde=True, bins=13)`. However, `bins` can be set as an `int`, as shown, or as a `list`, which defines the edges. As already stated by @JohanC, the distances for the bin edges are not consistent.